# Not looping and only writing to one card

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to write the 5 day weather index to 5 cards.
I am trying to loop it and place it in 5 different cards but it's writing to only one. I am stuck!!!!! help me, smart people! the loop is at i+=8 because the 5 day forecast is incremented by 3 hours. 3x8. So, I need it to pick from every 8th array. Thank you! <3

Here is my code for the loop of 5 day index.

```js
function forecast(cityID) {
  var fiveDayForecastAPI =
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + cityID + "&appid=" + myAPI;

  fetch(fiveDayForecastAPI)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      //console.log(data);
      let items = data.list;
       for (i = 0; i < items.length; i+= 8) {
        console.log(items[i]);
    
        let date= new Date((data.list[i].dt)*1000).toLocaleDateString();
        let iconcode= data.list[i].weather[0].icon;
        let iconurl="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+iconcode+".png";
        let tempC= data.list[i].main.temp;
        let tempF=(((tempC-273.5)*1.80)+32).toFixed(2);
        let humidity= data.list[i].main.humidity;
        
        $("#date"+i).text(date);
        $("#img"+i).html("<img src="+iconurl+">");
        $("#temp"+i).text(" " + tempF+" "+"F");
        $("#humidity"+i).text(" " + humidity + "%");
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you increasing the index by 8? `i+= 8`

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: because the 5-day forecast is set by 3-hour increments and so I had to pick 8th from the array. 3x8.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get the correct data from OpenWeatherMap.

in your **for** loop, you increment by 8 so that means you get 0, 8, 16, etc. that means `$("#date"+i).text(date);` would apply to elements `#date0`, `#date8`, `#date16`. It won't work if you have elements named `#date1`, `#date2`, `#date3`. Please verify that.

Also you may want to check `console.log(items.length);` to ensure it is at least 41 so the **for** can loop 5 times.